# Why does this vba macro ignores the value after an if else?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have two columns, the first one is a date with Year/Month format and the other a numerical value of an evaluation that i have done. I want to get the average value for each month with a macro( i need to do it so many times an a lot of data on it). So, i decided to create an array of dates and a Matrix of evaluation results. The goal is to group all numeric values by date and get the average per month. The problem is that this code ignores the value when the actual and last cells are different.

```
    Dim i As Integer 'number of rows
    Dim J As Integer 'manage row change
    Dim G As Integer 'manage column change
    Dim Fecha(48) As String
    Dim Matriz_FI(100, 100) As Double
    '--------------------------------------------------------------    --
    J = 0
    G = 0
    For i = 2 To 10
        If i = 2 Then
            Matriz_FI(J, G) = Sheets("Nueva Database").Cells(i, 11).Value
            Fecha(J) = Sheets("Nueva Database").Cells(i, 3).Value
            G = G + 1
        Else
            If (Sheets("Nueva Database").Cells(i, 3).Value = Sheets("NuevaDatabase").Cells(i - 1, 3).Value) Then
                'Column change in Matriz_FI
                Matriz_FI(J, G) = Sheets("Nueva Database").Cells(i, 11).Value
                G = G + 1
                MsgBox ("Same")
            Else
                'Row change in Matriz_FI
                J = J + 1
                Fecha(J) = Sheets("Nueva Database").Cells(i, 3)
                G = 0
                Matriz_FI(J, G) = Sheets("Nueva Database").Cells(i, 11).Value
                MsgBox ("Different")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Just fyi `Dim Date(48) As String` is a poor choice for variable name as `Date` is a built-in datatype in VBA

Comment: I have changed it! Thanks!

Comment: @Kubie it's also (confusingly) the name of a property getter in the `VBA.DateTime` standard library module. Interestingly, I can't get `Dim date(42) As String` to compile, it's a syntax error here (likely because it's reserved as a data type / keyword).